# Flutter Camera plugin error - The getter 'height' was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm working on a Camera app. I'm using the following Camera plugin - https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera

Here is my working code -

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<Null> main() async {
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new CameraApp(),
  ));

}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => new _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  CameraController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = new CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // camera widget
    Widget cameraView = new Container(
      child: new Row(children: [
          new Expanded(
            child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: new CameraPreview(controller)
                  )
                ]
            ),
          )
      ])
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          (!controller.value.initialized) ? new Container() : cameraView,

           // ---On top of Camera view add one mroe widget---

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I'm building the app I'm getting following errors...

```
I/flutter ( 2097): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CameraApp(dirty, state: _CameraAppState#a0666):
I/flutter ( 2097): The getter 'height' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 2097): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 2097): Tried calling: height
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you have the ternary operator inside the body of the Stack, you are creating the `Widget cameraView` regardless of whether it is going to be used - so it is being created whether `controller.value.initialized` is true or false. Adjust the code so that the CameraPreview tree is only built if it is needed, i.e. if initialized is true. For example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          (!controller.value.initialized) ? new Container() : buildCameraView(),

          // ---On top of Camera view add one mroe widget---
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildCameraView() {
    return new Container(
      child: new Row(
        children: [
          new Expanded(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: new CameraPreview(controller),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

As you suggest in your comment, you can move the ternary operator lower in your build tree, too, and replace just the AspectRatio with an empty Container.

Comment: This line ```(!controller.value.initialized) ? new Container() : cameraView,``` will not do the same thing?

Comment: See edited answer - the `CameraPreview` was being built even if not needed

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply & guiding me about the ```CameraPreview``` thing. I fixed that by using this line ```(!controller.value.initialized) ? new Container() : new AspectRatio(aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,child: new CameraPreview(controller))``` .

Comment: But, why your example codes are just like mine which I've already shared in my post. Infact your ```main()``` example code is also same which already I've posted!!! Anyway, I'm accepting your post as an answer. It'll be great if you add my solution line in your post. So that, other can easily get the solution in future if anyone will get stuck with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about main() - removed the redundant MaterialApp. You are right to suggest that you can insert the ternary operator anywhere; I wanted to leave the structure of your code as close to the original. The point remains that the original code tried to construct the AspectRatio before testing whether the controller was initialized or not.

Comment: Oh man, I just confused between my version of ```cameraView``` & your version of ```buildCameraView()```. I was thinking both are same. Just now it's stroked my mind that in my version was trying to build the widget irrespective of  Camera controller value initialized or not. That's a new thing I learned today. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: I've two more issue at this point with this Camera stuff. 1 - If I bring my app from background to foreground Camera stopped working. I need to restart the app the device app list. 2. When I'm changing device orientation, Camera view in the app not changing it's orientation accordingly. It always stays in Portrait mode. Do you've any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: I'd guess it's something to do with `W/MessageQueue(27569): Handler (android.graphics.SurfaceTexture$1) {cb57b72} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread` - do you see that? If you can describe your problem, this feels like a good topic for a new question.

Comment: In newer versions of the camera package: controller.value.initialized has changed to controller.value.isInitialized

Answer (score 0):

if even after using this check `(!controller.value.initialized) ? new Container() : cameraView`,still you are getting error that "getter 'height' was called on null",
and the error message is poping on your app only for fraction of second, then it means you are initializing your camera controller in `didChangeDependencies()`...if yes then use this technique.

```
bool cameraInitialized = false;
```

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (cameraInitialized == false) {
     
      final ScreenArguments arguments =
          ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

      int cameraIndex = Provider.of<XYZ>(context)
          .XX
          .firstWhere((element) => element.id == arguments.XX`enter code here`Id)
          .cameraIndex;
      controller = new CameraController(
          widget.cameras[cameraIndex], ResolutionPreset.medium);
      controller.initialize().then((value) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() {});
      });
     

    setState(() {
            cameraInitialized = true;
          });


    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```